# JS - How to correctly use setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have this function that executes on setTimeout and console.log returns the correct value for the variable I named time however the function is running with no delay when I run the code.  The code is server side for a game I am making.  The code is supposed to gradually restore health to the player after using an item.  My issue is with the settimeout function... also it works when I use it in the browser but not from my node console.

```
function balm(i){
    this_sql ="UPDATE game_moblist SET hp = least(max_hp, hp +"+Math.round(i/2)+") WHERE id ="+mobid;
    connection.query(this_sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) err=null
    });
    console.log(this_sql);
    this_sql = "SELECT hp, max_hp FROM  game_moblist WHERE id ="+mobid;   //emite catch all update pointint to hp..
    connection.query(this_sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        socket.emit ('updatemisc',handler,rows);//eval handler using args
        if (rows[0].hp==rows[0].max_hp){
            i=0;
            return i;
        }
    });
}
for (i=30;i>=0;i--){
   time=(31-i)*1000;
   console.log(time);
   setTimeout(balm(i),time);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct usage of setTimeout

```
setTimeout(balm, time, i);
```

You have to pass a function, then delay, and then args to the aforementioned function

Comment: Important to note that that is **only** correct in NodeJS (and Firefox). The ability to pass additional arguments to `setTimeout` is **not** a standard thing across environments, and will not work client-side. But it's quite true that [NodeJS supports it](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html#setTimeout), so +1.

Comment: @user1481372: All due respect, my answer works. But absolutely, pksunkara's answer works well in the environment you're using.

Comment: T.J. Crowder gave a very nice description on how setTimeout works. @user1481372, you should read that.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is here:

```
setTimeout(balm(i),time);
```

What that does is **call** `balm` and feed its return value in to `setTimeout`, which isn't what you want. You want to pass `setTimeout` a function that, when called, will call `balm` with a given `i` value. You do that like this:

```
setTimeout(makeHandler(i),time);
function makeHandler(index) {
    return function() {
        balm(index);
    };
}
```

That way, the `balm` function gets called later, and gets called with the `i` value as of when the timeout was *scheduled*. Without the `makeHandler` thing, all `balm` instances would see `i` as it was when they *ran* (e.g., they'd all see `-1`). This is because in JavaScript, a closure has enduring access to the variables in context; not a *copy* of them when the the closure was created. So all of them see the current value of `i`. (More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html))

(Note that on NodeJS — the environment you're using — and also on Firefox, you can use the **non-standard** extension to `setTimeout` that allows you to give arguments to pass to the function; see [pksunkara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11353229/157247). But for anyone looking to do this client-side on the web [rather than server-side with Node], beware, that is **not** standard.)

To illustrate this, here's an example (this one runs in a browser, but it's the same for server-side stuff like NodeJS):

```
(function() {

  // Wrong
  setTimeout(function() {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        show("wrong", i);
      }, i * 50);
    }
  }, 0);

  // Right
  setTimeout(function() {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      setTimeout(makeHandler(i), i * 50);
    }

    function makeHandler(index) {
      return function() {
        show("right", index);
      };
    }
  }, 500);

  function show(marker, val) {
    display("show (" + marker + "): " + val);
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/apibuz) | [source](http://jsbin.com/apibuz/edit)

Here's the output:

```
show (wrong): 5
show (wrong): 5
show (wrong): 5
show (wrong): 5
show (wrong): 5
show (right): 0
show (right): 1
show (right): 2
show (right): 3
show (right): 4
```

Comment: Great edit here. Its not completely obvious that `i` won't be the value you pass each time, but rather, the value that it ends up being by the time the function is actually run. Your `makeHandler` solves that. I'd +1 this answer again if I could...